# Get index in dart polymer repeat template

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I want to iterate over an enumerable and display a counter

```
<div template repeat="{{ name in names }}">
  ###. {{name}}
</div>
```

What should I put instead of `###` so it shows the position of the name:

```
1. John Doe
2. Jane Doe
3. etc...
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Polymer now has the ability to do this:

```dart
<template repeat="{{fruit in fruits | enumerate}}">
  <li>You should try the {{fruit.value}}. It is number {{fruit.index}}.</li>
</template>
```

Example taken from https://github.com/sethladd/dart-polymer-dart-examples/blob/master/web/iterate_loop_index/my_example.html

Comment: This no longer works in Polymer 0.5. Use Wolfram's solution instead.
I know this is answered 2 years ago, but let me note it for people who arrived from search.

Comment: This is still the way in Polymer 0.5. Maybe you meant 1.0?

Answer (score 7):

The other solutions do not work for me in Polymer 0.3.4 (anymore?), but there is [documentation on templates](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/template.html), including indexing while looping over a collection:

```dart
<template repeat="{{ foo, i in foos }}">
  <template repeat="{{ value, j in foo }}">
    {{ i }}:{{ j }}. {{ value }}
  </template>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

It was available in web_ui but is not yet available in Polymer.

> Web UI is the precursor to polymer.dart. Polymer.dart is almost at feature parity with Web UI. Below is a list of Web UI features that have not yet been implemented in polymer.dart:
>
> Value of index variable available inside of loops
>
> > https://www.dartlang.org/polymer-dart/#web-ui-parity

Until then, you can use `asMap` on the list and iterate over the `keys`:

```dart
  <template repeat="{{i in names.asMap().keys)}}">
    <div>{{i}}: {{names[i]}}</div>
  </template>
```

Comment: You don't even have to rewrite names for that.  {{ index in names.asMap.keys}}

Comment: @AlanKnight Very cool, thanks for the tip. I've updated my answer to use your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Not available yet, but you can use the quiver package as demonstrated in this SO answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18165968/1713985

Comment: You'd probably be better off creating a polymer expression global

Comment: That is what happens in the answer. Polymer expression used to be called fancysyntax :)